# Video Sequencer rendering low quality

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I'm having a problem with rendering my animation with video sequencer, my rendered frames are .PNG and high quality, yet when I render them in video sequencer the final result comes with poor quality
Outputs:
Encoding
Container: MPEG-4.
Autosplit Output is checked.
Video Codec: H.264.
Output Quality High Quality
Encoding Speed Realtime
Post Processing both Compositioning and sequencer are checked
Display Device sRGB
View Transform Filmic
Look high contrast
Squencer: sRGB

Comment: Can you show us a frame from the rendered .PNG and the same frame after you get it as an .MP4? it's possible your problem is due to the frames being compressed into a new file format and container, your solution might be rendering with a different file format like .AVI

Comment: or better: provide your blend file -> did you check output properties - x/y resolution?